# how to pass ocp-apim-trace=true as a query parameter to Azure API Management

Tags: azure, transformation, azure-api-management, azure-api-apps

I need to get the trace of an API call. I'm unable to set headers while calling the API management but will be able to pass the parameters in the URL as query parameters. I'm passing the subscription key successfully in the URL as a query parameter. How do I pass the apim-trace in the url so that I could get the trace url back in the response headers. I have tried the below

- trace = true
- Trace=true
- Apim-Trace=true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible, it has to be a header.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20930108)

Comment: The answer to the question is that Azure API Management expects ocp-apim-trace:true to be sent as a header, and at the moment there is no other way to request tracing.

Comment: If you extend your answer with the details you've mentioned in the previous comment and add any additional information to help others, who'll come/arrive to/at this post in the future, then my comment will be irrelevant and I will delete it immediately. If your answer is correct and valid, than please, **elaborate** on it. The system listed your answer for a reason, that is the sheer shortness of it.

Comment: @Rick Though I encourage Vitaly to expand this answer as you suggested, it is an answer indeed. The system does send very short answers to the review queue, but it is up to the reviewers to decide whether they actually attempt to answer the question or not.

Comment: @duplode Thanks for the clarification, after checking out the Azure API among several other resources, the answer is definitely correct. I still stand for my previous comment to Vitaliy to elaborate more on the answer to provide **a necessarily detailed answer** just exactly how he wrote an additional explanation in his comment.

Comment: Can this trace be set at Azure API Management instead of setting the trace parameter at the requesting resource ? Because, we're not currently allowed to set custom headers while sending a request.

Comment: Not at the moment, no. Is it an option for you to mock request being sent to APIM from Fiddler or Postman and get traces like that?

Answer (score 0):

ocp-apim-trace:true can be set only as header. Why don't you try "Application insights" for APIM. So you can get some analytics about each every call.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-app-insights